# Using complex cube roots to form a polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $x^3-x-1$, and $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $x^3-x-\alpha$, how would you form a polynomial with coefficients $\in \mathbb{Q}$ which has $\beta$ as a root?

I have tried explicitly computing the roots but I think that is too complicated, I'm sure there is some simple theorem that would apply. I had a look at using Vieta's formula, but I'm not sure how to apply that when one of the $a_n$ is $0$.

Comment: What kind of numbers are $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: They are $\in \mathbb{C}$, have edited now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Call $p(x)=x^3-x-1$ , so $p(\alpha)=0$.Since $\beta^3-\beta=\alpha$, then $p(\beta^3-\beta)=0$, and will result in a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. I don't know if it's the minimal polynomial, though.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful solution. I don't need the polynomial to be minimal, that would perhaps be a lot more challenging to find, or prove that this one is!

Answer (score 1):

I used a very powerful advanced method that turned out to give Bogdan’s result, so I threw away my computations. Let me instead look at Bogdan’s method from a more abstract viewpoint. We have a polynomial $f(X)=X^3-X$, an element $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ with $f(\alpha)=1$, and another complex number $\beta$ such that $f(\beta)=\alpha$. Thus $f\circ f(\beta)=1$. Let’s compute $f\circ f$: it’s $X^9-3X^7 + 3X^5 - 2X^3 + X$. So the (presumably) minimal polynomial for $\beta$ is $X^9-3X^7 + 3X^5 - 2X^3 + X-1$. In case you care, the discriminant of this nonic is (except maybe for the sign) $105869437069=11\cdot23^2\cdot37\cdot313\cdot1571$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't need that it is minimal, but I would be interested in how you would go about proving that this solution is, or how to find the minimal one if this one isn't?

Comment: If I may ask, what was your other, more advanced method?